# Npm run script with dynamically computed parameters

Tags: npm

I currently have this script in my package.json, for building the app to work on the cdn:

`"build:cdn": "ng build --prod --extract-css --output-hashing=none --deploy-url https://my-cdn.com/static/20181118000000/frontend/dist/"`

Where `20181118000000` is simply the convention for cache busting.
But that means that every time I want to build, I have to manually edit that value in the `build:cdn` script in package.json. Not to mention that I can't have the app running in watch mode...

How can I tell npm to dynamically compute that when running the command? Like `--deploy-url https://my-cdn.com/static/{getCurrentTimeStampHereAndFormatItTo('YYYYMMDDHHMMSS')}/frontend/dist/` whatever.
Especially since I would also like to use `npm run build:cdn -- --watch` to have it watching and build automatically when saving a file, while developing. Because local development also uses CDN - don't ask why :( - but it's a VM in the cloud, and with EACH change the code is automatically uploaded (thanks to WebStorm) through ftp to that development VM in the cloud, then I can refresh the browser to see the changes. Apparently, people preferred this over the Docker filesystem issues with mounted folders being slow.

Ideally, the solution should work on both Windows and Mac OS.

Comment: Just write a script in the language of your choice (shell or JS probably simplest) and invoke that instead.

Comment: well, unless there is a straight-forward and simple solution, I guess I'll have to see how can I do that (I have zero shell/bash scripting experience... and anyway, either bash or JS script will just add complexity to the simple use of `ng build` command)
maybe there is a simpler solution, I hope... I'll wait for a while before doing anything else.
thanks for the suggestion @jonrsharpe !

Comment: You can call that *from* the script, I just mean to build the parameters. You still run `npm run build:cdn` and it'd still end up calling the Angular CLI.